# Merging two rows into one row with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID        Column1        Column2        Column3
1         data1                         data3
1                        data2
```

from table above, may I perform a single query to get this? :

```
ID        Column1        Column2        Column3
1         data1          data2          data3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  MAX(Column1) AS Column1,
  MAX(Column2) AS Column2,
  MAX(Column3) AS Column3
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(Column1) AS Column1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Column2) AS Column2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Column3) AS Column3
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```